Problem Same letters render in different thickness with diffent colors. Therfore logo is distorted
Im rending two objects with each a different material, they are the same with the only diffence that the colors are different (the letters are png image with alpha channel, the background is a color, one is black letters on white background, other one is black letters on white background, other one is white letter on black background)
The problem is that the letters have different thicknesses in each image in the output render, however the png images have the same thickness.
Why are the letter rendering in different thicknesses?
You can see the difference looking at the letter 'A' middle triangle. Its bigger with black A and smaller with the white A.
This makes the logo look different comparing the pictures, which is a problem.
Thank you very much for your help.




It doesn't look like thickness is changing, it looks like you are looking at a cylinder from the side. What is the mesh we are seeing ?

As @Lutzi said, it does not look like the thickness is changing, the letters seem to be the same size: black/white comparison. It only seems to have moved compared to the icon above it, but that is due to the fact that the position of the object changed in the screenshots down and to the right, while the distance of the R to the boundary of the object is exactly the same (57 pixels): position of letter Everything else is just optical illusion (the triangle looks bigger white because brightness lets it appear larger).

Thanks for your efforts, but i the angle is completly the same. I have also done a comparison where I overlapped the both images with 50% transparency and it is clear that the white font is thicker. It appears like the angle has changed because the fonts have different thicknesses.
Anything other ideas you have?

Can you share the textures ? I don't see any thickness change or else I didn't understand your issue.

If you look at the triangle inside the letter 'A' you can see that is not the same size.
How would you like the textures to be shared? you can also have a look at the shader editor on the sceenshot.

tbh if you really want to have  an answer, instead of lettings us guess in the comments - provide your blend file and we can tell you what's going on. thx for your understanding.

Possibly not helped by:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiation_illusion .. actually well known in typography ... https://logogeek.uk/logo-design/optical-corrections/

As image texture it's the same, of course there is no actual distortion: black pixels turn to white and white ones turn to black; so, I think the problem lies on how grey antialiasing pixels are rendered: you can try inserting a color ramp/Map range/color curves node in the alpha connection and try tweaking the greys so to reach a balanced appearance of the two logos.
